# Issue in Radios Button validation in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, forms

I added the radios field in magento admin form  but have problem in validation,it is showing the all radios are required, and if a option is selected giving me an error for other options.

here is my code:

```
<?php 
$fieldset->addField('size', 'radios',
                       array(
                          'label' => Mage::helper('moduelname')->__('Maximum rim size you can handle
'),
                          'class' => 'required-entry',
                          'required' => false,
                           'name' => 'size',
                           'values' => array(array('value' => '17', 'label'=>'17 inch'),
                                       array('value' =>'18', 'label'=>'18 inch'),
                                       array('value' =>'19', 'label'=>'19 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'20', 'label'=>'20 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'21', 'label'=>'21 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'22', 'label'=>'22 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'23', 'label'=>'23 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'24', 'label'=>'24 inch')
                                      ,array('value' =>'25', 'label'=>'25 inch'),),
                    ));
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
'class' => 'required-entry',
```

to

```
'class' => 'validate-one-required-by-name',
```

hope this will work for you..

Comment: great that works